# Iterating over list of strings to see if particular string is present in all strings in the list (Java/Groovy)

Tags: java, loops, groovy

I have a list of strings (that I'm getting from another method) and want to verify that a certain string is present in ALL of the strings. I.e if the list is ["My name is Lindsey", "My name is Billy, "My name is John"] and I am testing to see if "name" is present in all strings, the method should return true. But if the list is ["My name is Lindsey", "My name is Billy, "I'm John"], the method should return false because "name" isn't in the last string. (I'm really new to programming, I apologize if I'm not using the right terms/symbology). Anyway, here is what I currently have:

```
def verifyEachSuggestionContainsValueOf(String value) {
        List<String> customerMessageSuggestions = customerMessageAutoSuggestions()
        boolean stringPresent = false
        for (String suggestion : customerMessageSuggestions) {
            if (suggestion.contains(value)) {
                stringPresent = true
            }else{
                return false
            }
        }
        return stringPresent
    }
```

This works, but I feel like there has to be a cleaner way of doing it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

***Edited to fix issue with stringPresent being returned inside For loop.

Comment: Note that your code is incorrect. The return should be outside the for loop.

Comment: You're right, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure Java:

```
return list.stream().allMatch(s -> s.contains("name"));
```

In Groovy:

```
return list.every { it.contains("name") }
```

Comment: Won't this return a list? I just want a true/false response.

Comment: Both of these return boolean. Read the javadoc.  The first option allows for the possibility of evaluating the list in parallel (if it makes sense to do that from a performance point of view).

Answer (score 0):

```
def verifyEachSuggestionContainsValueOf(String value) {
    List<String> customerMessageSuggestions = 
        customerMessageAutoSuggestions()
    for (String suggestion : customerMessageSuggestions) {
        if (!suggestion.contains(value)) {
            return false
    }
    return true
}
```

The declaration of the boolean variable is unnecessary. If any of the strings does not contain the desired substring, the method can immediately return false and exit the method. Else, it returns true.